# how to retrieve data from jsp and store in database?

Tags: html, sql, database, jsp

I want to fetch data from a html page and use those values in a jsp page and store those values in a database. Can you please help?

**my html page:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>reading values</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="click.jsp">name:
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""/><br/> <br/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
    <button type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">reset</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**my jsp page:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Click.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    Connection conn=null;
    String u=null;
    u=request.getParameter("name");
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/***", "admin", "*****");
    Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
    String sql= "INSERT INTO (table name) VALUES (?)";
    PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    prep.setString(1,u);
    prep.executeUpdate();

    prep.close();
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)